# JSON resume-cli can't init

Tags: node-modules

I installed resume-cli globally using `npm install -g resume-cli` but when I try to initialize it I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module '../init.js'
Require stack:
- /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/resume-cli/build/main.js
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? That would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to this GitHub issue https://github.com/jsonresume/resume-cli/issues/474 this seems to be a bug since version 3.0.1.

Version 3.0.0 works fine:

```
npm i resume-cli@3.0.0
```